# Why do we stick to single valued functions?

Tags: functions

The definition of a function of real variables given in my book was that a function is a rule which assigns to each element in the domain exactly one element of the range. I am new to what a mathematical structure is, but from what I have gathered so far, if I agreed to accept a definition, then I cannot invoke any rules other than those which relate the definition.

Was this structure (definition) imposed to obey the same mathematical structure of algebra (definitions and rules of equality, addition, and multiplication)? For instance, how would we define $\sqrt{4} + 4$ as $+2+4$ or $-2+4$?

From this point of view a multi-valued mapping violates the above definition and cannot be regarded as a function, since
a multi-valued mapping assigns to a single element in a set two or more distinct elements of another set.

For example, let $y=\sqrt{x}$. To find its inverse, we break down the curve into a union of single-valued pieces at the points of vertical tangents, which occurs at the origin and consider one branch at a time where the function is bijective. Why do we do this?

Graphically,
$\sqrt{4}= \pm 2 $. What is the problem with plotting multiple ordered pairs from the mappings to sketch the curve of $\sqrt{x}$, where $ f:4 \rightarrow \pm 2 $ or $ (4,-2) $ and $ (4,2) $ and forming the inverse by reflecting the graph about y=x.

To clarify in case the readers of this question are confused if it seems I am asking different unrelated questions, what I am trying to say in short is: did we state the existence conditions (injectivity and surjectivity) to take advantage of the mathematical structure and can we use some of the mathematical structure if we violate the definition? Namely graphically, we can plot multivalued functions but can we perform arithmetic without it being ambiguous?

Comment: The notion that a function maps each input to exactly one output is known as the function being well defined. I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the idea isn't really to like "obey any mathematical" laws, but the point is that a function that maps an input to several possible outputs would be completely useless. Any other definition of a function would not be useful (not that it violates "existing mathematical laws" per se, but just that it is not useful)

Comment: $\sqrt4=2$, not $\sqrt4=\pm2$. That's by definition of square root (at least, if you're working in the real numbers – for the complex numbers, life is more complicated).

Comment: I'll disagree with @AlanChung here. Set-valued maps, or multifunctions, are actually quite common in mathematics, at least at higher levels. Complex analysis is probably the most elementary example of a field that regularly uses multifunctions, but they're used in other fields too. For example, in non-linear analysis, you'll find plenty of mentions of USCOs, upper-semicontinuous (set-valued) operators, or CUSCOs, which are convex-valued USCOs. I, myself, spent my PhD studying metric projections, which are family of set-valued maps.

Comment: I don't know too much, but we actually *do* study multi-valued functions! In fact, you might have conisdered it yourself. Instead of considering the graph $\{(x, \sqrt{x}) : x \geq 0\}$, we can consider both branches at the same time!! That is, we look at the (non-)graph $\{(x, \sqrt{x}) : x \geq 0\} \cup \{(x, -\sqrt{x}) : x \geq 0\}$ for the square root function. I see this in the theory of half-integer modular form, where the definitions involve the square root of something, so instead of making some arbitrary choice, we look at the Metapletic group, which is

Comment: essentially the same idea: we simply stack copies of the objects together along with every possible choice of square roots. Then we do analysis or whatever on it. And for the non-graph I described above, you can do analysis on it too. If you plot it, it's just a rotated parabola :)

Comment: A function $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ is quite common. A vector in a multidimensional Euclidean space is an ordered set of values so we routinely define multi-valued functions of multiple inputs. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Some food for thought: if we refer to $\sqrt{4}$ as both square roots of $4$ (i.e. $2$ and $-2$), keeping track of both possibilities, then naively writing $\sqrt{4} \times \sqrt{4}$ would give you $\pm 4$, not just $4$. It might be a bitter pill to swallow to say that $\sqrt{4}$ is not all the solutions to $x^2 = 4$, but I think it's a more bitter pill to say that $\sqrt{x} \times \sqrt{x}$ is not necessarily $x$ (though, of course, $\sqrt{x \times x}$ is already not necessarily equal to $x$, so maybe it isn't so bad).

Comment: This is probably because multi-valued functions can be reduced to single-valued functions. Namely, a multifunction from $A$ to $B$ can be understood as a single-valued function from $A$ to the power set of $B$.

Comment: The graph you want to describe by $y=\sqrt x$ is perfectly well described by $y^2=x$. That leaves us free to use the symbol $\sqrt{\phantom{0}}$ for other purposes where it's convenient for it to be a function.

Comment: Because we say $\sqrt4=2$, that is, $\sqrt{\phantom{0}}$ is only the non-negative square root, when we want both square roots we write $\pm\sqrt4$ (although that notation is a little informal).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Is a Function Defined As Having Only One Y-Value Output?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271613/why-is-a-function-defined-as-having-only-one-y-value-output)

Comment: Mathematicians like the "functions are arrows from one space into another space" description that being single-valued affords. They like it so much that in more abstract settings, generalized functions are sometimes just called "arrows." All definitions are trivially true, but only some are useful. The single-valued function definition has proven *very* useful. If you like, this is the math obverse to the science idea that models are good only inasmuch as they conform to experiment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we focus so much in math on functions (as a subclass of relations)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061735/why-do-we-focus-so-much-in-math-on-functions-as-a-subclass-of-relations)

Comment: I see what you guys mean by multi-valued functions; what I interpreted the OP as saying was that a function $f(x)$ "sometimes" outputs $a$ and "sometimes" outputs $b$, not a set-valued function. Perhaps I misinterpreted! @TheoBendit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The definition that requires functions to be single valued is so useful in so many contexts that mathematicians don't tinker with it.

So for example, the square root function $\sqrt{\phantom{b}}$ with domain the nonnegative reals always returns the nonnegative root. That doesn't mean the equation $x^2 = 2$ has just one root. It means that if you want to talk about both they are $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$.

There are other places in mathematics where you want to study   maps from some domain to sets of values in some other domain. You just don't call them “functions”. Or you define them as functions with codomain a set of sets. Or you call them “multi-valued functions”, which is strange from a grammatical point of view but well understood.

(I am pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but can't find the duplicate.)

Comment: Wait, I thought the term "relation" was used in stead of "multivalued function"?

Comment: @Vergilius They’re pretty similar, but “multivalued function” is used when we still want to think about it “functionally”. For example, you would often expect that the output $f(x)$ for a multivalued function $f$ is in some sense “discrete”, with no such expectation existing for general relations.

Comment: @Vergilius You are correct.

Comment: @Vergilius math is a big place, and there is much variation in terminology. For example, this intro to monotone operator theory mentions both the terms "relation" and "multi valued function" along with some others at the beginning of Section 2 (itself titled Relations) [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/monotone_primer.pdf].

Answer (score 5):

There was a long-ish blog post relevant to this a few years back by the estimable Tim Gowers, which in turn sparked an extended 64 response discussion.

I'm not going to try to summarise the high spots, as it is nearly all really worth a read.

[Here's a link](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/).

Comment: Lovely post, not quite on topic but well worth the link/read.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is more technical than the level of the question, but hopefully it will be useful to someone. In mathematics, there *is* a more general concept than a function, namely a *relation*.

In set theory, a relation from $A$ to $B$ is typically defined as a subset of $A\times B$, and a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is defined as a relation from $A$ to $B$ such that (i) for every $a\in A$, there is a $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$, and (ii) for every $x\in A$ and $y,y'\in B$, if $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,y')\in f$, then $y=y'$.

Conditions (i) and (ii) imply that if $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, then for every $x\in A$, there is one and only one $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in f$; this $y$ is written as $f(x)$. However, if all we know is that $f$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$, then for each $x\in A$, it is possible that there is more than one $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in f$. It is also possible that there is no $y$ at all such that $(x,y)\in f$! This means that the notation $f(x)$, as defined previously, does not make sense for general relations.

However, there is a way out. Given a relation $f$ from $A$ to $B$ and an $x\in A$, we can define $f(x)$ as follows:
$$
f(x)=\{y\in B:(x,y)\in f\} \, .
$$
This definition clashes with the previous one if $f$ happens to be a function: if $f(x)=y$ according to the first definition, then $f(x)=\{y\}$ according to the second one. As you can see though, the two definitions are closely linked.

A relation $f$ from $A$ to $B$ thus induces a function $A\to\mathcal P(B),a\mapsto f(a)$ (second definition). In your example, if we make the slightly unorthodox choice of defining the square root as a relation $S$ from $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $(x,y)\in S$ if and only if $y^2=x$, then $S$ induces the "multi-valued function" $\varphi:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ given by
$$
\varphi(x)=\{\sqrt x,-\sqrt x\} \, ,
$$
where $\sqrt x$ is defined in the usual way. Thus, a real-valued "multi-valued function" can be seen as a *bona fide* function whose outputs are sets of real numbers.

Although this way of thinking about square roots might seem quite natural, it has some quite serious drawbacks. The first drawback is one you identified in your question, namely that arithmetic with multi-valued functions or relations appears to become ill-defined. Although you *could* define addition on sets of real numbers, this would feel quite clunky in practice. The second drawback is that concepts such as continuity no longer make sense for multi-valued functions (not unless you define a topology on $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, at least, and again there are questions of how useful and natural such a topology would be). The closest one gets to taking the derivative of a multi-valued function in calculus is with the implicit function theorem, and even in this case, the idea is that we can pretend that a multivalued function is single-valued if we "zoom in" enough. Thus, from the standpoint of calculus, relations and multi-valued functions are less fundamental than ordinary functions.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, the angle $\theta$ is multiple-valued (unless one specifies a interval in which $\theta$ varies).  This turns out to be significant in a field such as de Rham cohomology, where understanding that the differential 1-form $d\theta$ on the unit circle is *closed* but not *exact* depends on emphasizing the difference between *single-valued* and *multiple-valued.*

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do with multiple-valued "functions", you can do with single-valued functions. This is yet another instance where maths and computer coding really help each other out in terms of understanding the other - it's basically a question of "implementing" the desired functionality using a simpler set of basic tools, like in coding, implementing a binary tree using an array with suitable addressing. And one thing mathematicians like to do is to try and keep the set of basic tools for "implementational" use as simple as possible, hence single-valued functions would be preferred to multi-valued functions as the more basic concept.

One way to implement multi-valued functions using single-valued ones is to make the *codomain* of what *would be* the multi-valued function something other than a number, such that it packages the multiple values together. A common way to do this is to use sets: a "multi-valued function" with domain $D$ and codomain $C$ becomes instead a single-valued function with domain $D$ and codomain $2^C$, so that the multiple output values become bundled together into a single set value. When this definition is in play, the statement $\sqrt{4} = \{ +2, -2 \}$ is true.

Another way to do it, is to keep the codomain as-is, change what the *domain* of the multi-valued function is. The logic here is that multi-valued functions like $\sqrt{\cdot}$ can be understood as arising from the fact that they are trying to invert "lossy" operations, that is to say, operations (here, squaring) that lose information. Because the information is missing, we cannot unambiguously select a single value with which to define a function. The "codomain" approach, then, basically consists of asking the user of the multi-valued function for more - that is to say, to supply that missing information. A simple way for the square root would be to include along with the number we want to take that square root of, a second variable indicating the *sign* of the number *we presume was squared* to create it. Note this is *not* the same thing as a square root operation taking a signed number as input - rather, it must take a sign *and* a number *separately*. There is no standard notation for this - we might be tempted to, say, write $\sqrt{(+, 4)}$, which then is the same thing as "$2$", and $\sqrt{(-, 4)}$, which then is the same as $-2$.

*Fortuitously,* however, it turns out the notations $\pm \sqrt{n}$ also essentially have an identical effect; and this is likely a reason why we just say "make $\sqrt{n}$ the positive root of $n$ and get it over with". But that isn't the case in more complex cases, e.g. the inverse trigonometric functions, or the *complex* logarithmic function. In those cases, one may imagine the second argument to be, say, a *range* in which we are presuming the output angle came from. We might, say, define $\mathrm{arcsin}(a, b; x)$ - again, not a "standard" notation, but one we are introducing to demonstrate the principle - to be the value of the inverse sine of $x$ under the assumption the angle came from the interval $[a, b)$, where we require that $(a, b)$ are subject to the constraints (i.e. limiting the scope of our extended *domain*), to only those pairs of the form $\left(\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\tau}{2}, \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\tau}{2}\right)$, for integers $n$. I.e. $\mathrm{arcsin}(0, 0.3; 1)$, is a domain error.

Of course, there is one more caveat here, and that's that in either case, we often deal with expressions like $2 + \sqrt{4}$ and the like, yet we have a "data type incompatibility" here: if we defined $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in terms of taking a pair with a sign, it is not allowed to take a "$2$" as input, and if we defined it take numbers but produces a set as output, now "$+$" chokes, because it "expected" to take two real numbers, not a real number and a set. Hence, we have to either make some definitions for how we are to, say, promote "$4$" to a pair like $(+, 4)$ - which is, in effect then doing the same thing as simply arbitrarily choosing a single-valued branch, *or* we have to define how that $+$ is supposed to operate when one of its arguments is not another real number, but a set of real numbers. The latter isn't unheard of at all - typically, the way we do it is just elementwise:

$$a + S := \{ a + s : s \in S \}$$

for adding the real number $a$ and set $S$. Then $2 + \sqrt{4} = \{0, 4\}$ - but the point is, you still have to make this definition and be clear you are doing that, or else, you might run into some form of incorrect mathematical reasoning.

Regardless of the method chosen, however, the point stands: **anything you can do with multiple-valued functions you can do with single-valued functions**, so that multiple-valued functions provide no greater expressive power to your language. (They also provide no less, since a single-valued function is in effect a degenerate case of a multiple-valued function.) Thus, as a matter of *mathematical economy*, it's useful to simply not use them, and instead employ single-valued functions more artfully ...

... except that, unfortunately, unlike in computer coding where the compiler ensures our code *must* conform *exactly*, maths *in practice* kind of blurs some of the idealism of the unambiguous formal language it tries to represent into messy notation and usage that is formally nonsense, and thus you will see things where a "multi-valued function symbol" gets tossed around carelessly as though it were a single-valued function. Which can lead to trouble unless you're actually aware of what is going on, which a skilled mathematician will be, but which will cause a learner many hours of frustration with "well what's wrong with it?!" in things like

$$1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1} = i \cdot i = -1.$$

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, in order to be precise and unambiguous, definitions are often stated in a way that's terse and somewhat abstract; the price we pay for this is that not everything that the definition implies is necessarily immediately obvious - you have to spend some time thinking it through and working things out, building intuition.

The requirement is there to ensure there is no ambiguity on what the result of the function is when you give it a certain input. For the same input, it always returns the same output.

However, stepping outside the realm of real-valued functions of a real variable, and thinking more generally ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))), remember that the codomain of a function can be *any set*. Therefore, the output can be a *composite object* (in particular, the result itself can be a *single object* composed of multiple values), or even something that you can use to derive multiple values from it.

For example, the codomain can be a set of ordered pairs. For each input, the function can map to *exactly one ordered pair* - it's still just one element of the codomain - but then you can extract multiple values from the result.

[image]
Here, $f(1) = (-2, 2)$, $f(2) = (1, 1)$ and $f(3) = (1, 1)$. (Image modified from the original [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#/media/File:Injection_keine_Injektion_2a.svg))

Or, something slightly more outlandish, suppose the codomain is a set of triangles expressed as triplets of points in the Cartesian plane - and suppose you have some function mapping each input to a single triangle. Then from the output, you can extract all kinds of results (coordinates, angles, area, ...)

Or, consider something quite common - vector-valued functions: the outputs can be vectors, with any number of dimensions.

The elements of the codomain can also be sets themselves.
[image]

You can even have something like a family of related real functions controlled by some parameter as your codomain, and then you can have a function that takes a real number, and for each input outputs a single function from that family. And then you can use the resulting function to extract values by applying it to elements of its domain.

[image]

So you *can* have multiple resulting values "bundled" together, or otherwise somehow encoded. Again, what you can't have is output ambiguity given a certain input.

Similarly, you can have composite objects as *inputs*. E.g. $f(x, y)$ can be understood as taking a single ordered pair: $f((x, y))$.

Now, when it comes to doing algebra on the reals, if you have a function in there, it's preferable for it to return a real number, to make everything work smoothly. So the output of $\sqrt{\phantom{b}}$ isn't defined to be some composite object like a set or an ordered pair, but rather something that returns a single real value.