# Coequalizers in categories of relations and partial functions

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Rel}$ be the category whose morphisms are triples $(X, R, Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $R$ is a relation between $X$ and $Y$ and let $\mathbf{PFun}$ be the subcategory of $\mathbf{Rel}$ where the relations $R$ are required to be partial functions. I believe I can prove that $\mathbf{Rel}$ does not have coequalizers but $\mathbf{PFun}$ does. Can anyone give me a pointer to a reference for this.

(I found this [promising book](http://math.ubbcluj.ro/~calu/BOO-0-14.pdf), but it is incomplete and, tantalisingly, it ends just before the place where it would have answered the question about $\mathbf{Rel}$. It does usefully point out that some authors use the name $\mathbf{Rel}$ for something else, which is why I spelt out the definition above.)

Comment: Indeed $\mathbf{PFun}$ has coequalisers. The easiest way to see this is to show that it is equivalent to the category of pointed sets.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure you may be right if you already have a proof that the category of pointed sets has coequalisers, but this was a reference request.

Comment: Again, not a reference (but I think these facts are elementary enough that no reference is needed), but I gave an example of two relations with no equalizer (and by taking the "opposite" relations get get relations with no coequalizer) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354779/the-category-set-seems-more-prominent-important-than-the-category-rel-why-is-th/870483#870483). The idea behind this example is that in $\mathsf{Rel}$, every homset has cardinality $2^n$ for some $n$, but it's easy to exhibit a diagram whose set of (co)cones with given vertex is not of this form.